# Integral of non-Gaussian distributions

Tags: differential-calculus

In physics, we have an non-Gaussian Distribution which can be simply written as $f(x)=\exp(-ax^2-bx^3)$, and we may need to calculate the integral of this distribution, simply written as $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$, so how to calculate this integral?

and then we may calculate the expectation functions like $\langle xx\rangle=\int_0^\infty xxf(x)dx$.

Maybe you can refer to arxiv:astro-ph/0210603https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0210603, and the question is just how to gain equation (5.13) from Distribution of (5.12).

Comment: Even for a=0, b=1, where your integral is pretty much Gamma(1/3), there is no closed form formula; calling it Gamma(1/3) is just giving a name to the integral we can’t evaluate.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha will tell you this integral can be written in terms of a hypergeometric function; I don't quite understand the question you write with reference to Maldacena's paper...

Comment: Thanks to David Loeffler, I know that result of Gamma(1/3) and finally know the reason.

Comment: In fact I think this question is from the Maldacena's paper, and I want to understand the method of calculating expectations of the non-Gaussion distributions. Thanks to Carlo Beenakker, but it seems different from Maldacena's "simple results"